# Tying to delete an old Facebook page, receive "X can't be deleted" / "This business is ineligible for deletion"

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I'd like to delete an old Facebook page for an old business that closed 12 months ago.

At https://business.facebook.com/settings/info?business_id=xxx I click "Permanently Delete Business" and receive a message:

> X can't be deleted

> Once you've deleted your Business Manager, this
> action can't be reversed. This business is ineligible for deletion.
> Learn more about why and how to fix this.

If I click "[Troubleshoot why you can't delete your Business Manager](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/2186488678264121?id=180505742745347)" I see that business pages cannot be deleted if:

- there are outstanding ad account balances
- payment methods still exist on the ad account
- apps have been added to your business, and haven't been removed
- there are no people with full access to your page
- if the page has system users
- if a WhatsApp Business account with at least one linked phone number is connected to your business account, you must first remove the WhatsApp account before you can delete your business account
- if you turned on customised lead access for a Page in your business account, you can't delete your business account
- you're running ads about social issues, elections or politics (US)

None of these items applies to my business page or my business page's ad account.

The same help page says `If you still need help, contact our support team` (`https://www.facebook.com/business/support/contact-us`) which is a 404.

So Facebook's help article says my problem shouldn't exist, but if it does to contact them, but I can't contact them because their contact page doesn't exist.

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?